# Service worker available event not fired with angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have created application in angular 7 with PWA support. In which, I have created new update popup with swUpdate. Earlier its working proper and show me new update popup once I have upload new build on server. But, its not working.

Here in my code.

```
constructor() {
    this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
      this.promptUser();
    });

    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      interval(2 * 60 * 60).subscribe(() => this.swUpdate.checkForUpdate()
        .then(() => console.log('checking for updates')));
    }
}

promptUser() {
    this.swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(() => {
       location.reload();
    });
}
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev",
        "build:dev": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev",
        "build:staging": "ng build --prod --configuration=staging",
        "build:prod": "ng build --prod --configuration=production",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^7.2.9",
        "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.1",
        "@angular/common": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/core": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
        "@angular/forms": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/material": "^7.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/pwa": "^0.10.7",
        "@angular/router": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.3",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.2",
        "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
        "angular-moment-timezone": "^1.7.1",
        "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
        "angular2-cookie-law": "^6.2.0",
        "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
        "angular7-data-table": "^1.0.13",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "core-js": "^2.6.3",
        "exceljs": "^2.0.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "firebase": "^5.8.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
        "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
        "ng-http-loader": "^3.2.0",
        "ng-recaptcha": "^4.2.1",
        "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
        "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
        "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
        "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.4.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.7",
        "@angular/cli": "^7.3.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.2",
        "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
        "husky": "^1.3.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.3.0",
        "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~3.1.6"
    },
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "path": false,
        "os": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "stream": false,
        "http": false,
        "tls": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "https": false,
        "net": false
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any have have any suggestions on this. Its really needs.

Comment: can you share me what error you getting?

Comment: I m not getting any error. Just console the checking for updates text after that nothing happens. Once I have hard refresh the tab latest build will be loaded. Once I have close tab and reopened tab its loaded old build data.